# Powershell csv formatting

Tags: powershell

I am exporting A users from AD. It's working fine , I only have issue in the export file.

Current Output

> A000354   CN=ATX_PUTTY,OU=Personal,OU=abc,OU=xyz,DC=dd,DC=pp,DC=net

Desired Output

> ```
> A000354  ATX_PUTTY
> ```

```
$FilePath = "c:/LocalData/A_Users.csv"
$OuDomain = "OU=Personal,OU=Personal,OU=abc,OU=xyz,DC=dd,DC=pp,DC=net"
$users = Get-QADUser -SamAccountName [A]* -searchRoot $OuDomain -SizeLimit 0 -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties
$result = $users | % {
    $SamAccountName = $_.SamAccountName
    if ($lastDomain -eq $_.dn) {
        $lastDomain = ""
    } else {
        $lastDomain = $_.dn
    }

    $_.MemberOf | % {
        $user = New-Object -TypeName PsObject -Property @{
                "Domain" = $lastDomain
                "SamAccountName" = $SamAccountName
                "Group" = $_
            }
        $user
    }
}

$result | sort-object SamAccountName | Select-Object SamAccountName, Group |  Export-CSV $FilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

Now I am getting .....Output like

```
A000354 CN=ATX_PUTTY,OU=Personal,OU=abc,OU=xyz,DC=dd,DC=pp,DC=net
```

I want to Output like below , I dont want CN= and ,OU=Personal,OU=abc,OU=xyz,DC=dd,DC=pp,DC=net

```
A000354  ATX_PUTTY
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Get-Help Export-CSV -detailed` to see that there is a `-NoTypeInformation` switch that does just the thing you need:

> -NoTypeInformation [] Omits the type information from the CSV file. By default, the first line of the CSV file contains
>   "#TYPE " followed by the fully-qualified name of the type of the .NET
>   Framework object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select-Object` to pick the properties you want:

```
$result | sort-object SamAccountName | Select-Object SamAccountName, Group |  Export-CSV $FilePath
```